# How can I display rhinoslider caption in combination with lightbox2?

Tags: caption, lightbox2, captions

I have a fully working rhinoslider and lightbox2. The images slide but are also clickable, when there clicked the nice lightbox2 pops up. But for some reason the captions in the slider won't display when the other link is above it.

My code:

```
<ul id="slider"><a href="images/1big.jpg" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]" title="test"><li><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" title="test" /></li></a> </ul>
```

Does anyone know why the captions won't display? And is there a solution to this problem?

http://rhinoslider.com/
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should fix your markup.

```
<ul id="slider">
    <li>
        <a href="images/1big.jpg" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]" title="test">
            <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" title="test" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If the caption won't work afterwards, please make sure you enabled them in the settings of Rhinoslider.

If they still won't work try to set the captions manually: http://rhinoslider.com/tricks/html-captions/